# Set Angular HostBinding css class to value with function?

Tags: css, angular, angular2-hostbinding

I have a component that uses `@HostBinding` to set a class:

`@HostBinding('class.dark-1') true;`

Which works fine.  However, now I need to create a function in my component to change the class dynamically.

For example, from `dark-1` to `light-2` when a button in the component is clicked.

I know how to create the function and call it from a button, but how do I change the class in the hostbinding and refresh the UI with the new class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinply give it a property name:

```
@HostBinding('class.dark-1') isDark = true;
```

Then you can change it:

```
this.isDark = false;
```

Or change entire className:

```
@HostBinding('class') className = 'dark-1';

this.className = 'light-1';
```

Comment: can you do a similar thing with attributes that might contain a value?

Comment: For any attribute you can do `@HostBinding('attr.data-my-attribute') myDataAttr = 'value';`

Having said that, I don't know why you would want to do this with Angular.  :) Maybe if you're making a web-component that's to be used outside an Angular app, then yes, otherwise I see no reason...

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a `clicked` flag when clicking the button, and set the classes with getters:

```
@HostBinding("class.dark-1") public get classDark1() {
    return !this.clicked;
}

@HostBinding("class.light-2") public get classLight2() {
    return this.clicked;
}

private clicked = false;

public onClick() {
    this.clicked = true;
}
```